# Matching error patterns using spacy matcher issue. Giving a match where it is not supposed to

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

Iam working on finding a error pattern using spacy matcher in python (from spacy.matcher import Matcher)

1. "The manufacturer recommends\nthe wall is painted" - should match the pattern
2. "The manufacturer recommends\nthat wall is painted" - should not match the pattern (but spacy matching this sentence)
3. "Make sure\nthe we are ready." - should match the pattern
4. "Make sure\nthat we are ready." - should not match the pattern (but spacy matching this sentence)

A pdf document will be uploaded and the sentence might be split into two lines. So "\n" might come in between sentence. Iam specifically interested in "\n" after recommends, shows(refer pattern1) and after "make" or "sure"(refer pattern2)."\n" are considered as a individual token by spacy . Cases 2 & 4 mentioned are not giving the expected results . Please help

I have created two patterns to match for scenarios like

```
pattern1 = [
    {
        "LOWER": {"IN": ["recommends", "shows"]}
    },
    {
        "TEXT": {"REGEX": "\n"},
        "OP": "?"
    },
    {
        "LEMMA": {"NOT_IN": ["that"]},
    }
]

pattern2 = [
    {
        "LOWER": "make"
    },
    {
        "TEXT": {"REGEX": "\n"},
        "OP": "?"
    },
    {
        "LOWER": "sure"
    },
    {
        "TEXT": {"REGEX": "\n"},
        "OP": "?"
    },
    {
        "TEXT": {"NOT_IN": ["that"]}
    }
]
```

I tried changing the patterns like

1. instead of using "REGEX" for "\n", directly giving the "\n" itself
2. Using "that" directly instead of keeping inside "NOT_IN"

The issue is not resolved